# Google Drive API: Import file from other account

Tags: google-drive-api, httprequest

I got a file shared from account A, and account B can read-only this file.

In [DriveWeb](https://drive.google.com/drive/#my-drive), i can import it easy. Then with [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), how account B can import that file (without transfer).

Thankyou.

Comment: Which language are you working on?

Comment: I'm using C# but hate Google Drive Lib, then i write [new lib](https://github.com/tqk2811/Cloud-Manager/tree/master/Cloud/GoogleDrive) using httprequest. I'm self study C# then don't laugh the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are familiar with Authentication and have basic idea on setting up a an Authenticated Drive service. If not, go through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/dotnet) or [this](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/) tutorial which should get you started with the API.

Shared files can be accessed by the receiver inside their Drive, under the ownership of person who shared it. Such files do not take up your quota and can only be accessed as long as the permission prevails. So I assume by "Import", you meant to obtain the ownership of the file and save it in Account B.

Okay, let `Service` be Authenticated Drive Service of Account B. Assuming Account B have the permission to access the required file in Account A. If not, [Insert Permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) first.

`FileId` being the `Id` of the file to be copied and `ParentId` being the `Id` of the parent directory to which the file is to be copied, here's a method to make a copy of the shared file.

```
public void CopyFile(DriveService Service, string FileId, string ParentId)
{
    try
    {
        File FileToCopy = Service.Files.Get(FileId).Execute();

        File copiedFile = new File();
        copiedFile.Title = FileToCopy.Title;
        copiedFile.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = ParentId } };

        Service.Files.Copy(copiedFile, FileToCopy.Id).Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thank to reply, i can test in [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert) and i found it. It is Parents.insert method, and your reply is Files.Copy method (it create new file, not "import" )